# WYSIWYG editor that doesn't modify HTML

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I have a problem with FCKEditor and TinyMCE.

I need a WYSIWYG editor that doesn't modify HTML when changing views (like fixing broken HTML etc.)

I have tried different configuration parameters, but none of them turn off html modification entirely.

Is there a WYSIWYG editor that doesn't modify HTML even when its broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very hardly. The actual WYSIWYG editing is done by components integrated in the browsers ([Midas](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Midas) in Firefox, [contentEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28VS.85%29.aspx) tag in IE). In my experience, they all tend to auto-fix broken HTML as best as they can. All the WYSIWYG editors build around that functionality.

I think some degree of auto-fixing is kind of inherent to any WYSIWYG editor, because broken HTML can't really be edited.

What are you trying to get around? Try to describe what your actual problem is and maybe somebody can come up with a different way.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but wasn't sure:)

Problem was that sometimes we need to insert HTML generated by other tools without modifications.
I think that somekind of menu that lets you choose between WYSIWYG and simple HTML inserting would do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe FCKEditor, TinyMCE, and many other WYSIWYG editors use editable iframes.  This means they allow the browser to decide how to modify the HTML and is more of a builtin function (builtin in the sense of the browser).  Someone please jump in here if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your html on you desktop and copy and pasting it to your browser editor
just make sure you use the same mode on each editor ie html to html or wysiwyg to wysiwyg

Here is the desk top editor I use and it works well

Technology is moving so fast it is impossible to keep up and learn how to use all the new tool coming out
I like to try out new thing when I have the time but
I still need to get the thing done that I need to do
So I like to do the bulk of my html editing on my desk top and this is the faithful tool I use

For anything you do online it is important to understand how things work
so you are not at the mercy of others
I believe that it is important to understand and be able to edit html and create web pages
here is the easy way that I have found to achieve this

If You are looking for help with Website Creation then I would suggest that you have a look at kompozer it is an updated version of

nvu
and looks the same and operates almost the same but is a more stable software as almost all of the bugs have been removed

Go to this site http://kompozer-nvu.info/ if you are interested in a set of video tutorial that will make you a expert in no time at all

Have a look at what Kompozer can do
It is my website editor of choice as it is free

I learned to use it fully with videos

Go to the site and get the free video they are enough to get you started

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.richtexteditor.com/demo/.

We've used it for 1 year and found the html code is well kept in this editor.